# Is there a simpler solution for arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="files" class="files">
<p>Jellyfish.jpg</p>
<p>Lighthouse.jpg</p>
<p>Jellyfish (1).jpg</p>
<p>Koala.jpg</p>
</div>
```

For add names in array i do next:

```
var AllFilesName = $("#files").html();
var AllFilesName = AllFilesName.replace('<p>', '');
var AllFilesName = AllFilesName.split('</p>');
```

Tell me please is there a simpler solution for arrays ?

Comment: Whilst not related to your question. I would highly recommend you use an ul > li instead of div > p. As this is a list of files.

Comment: Also, you should only put `var` in front of the first use of your variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to collect all those values in a single array,

```
var arrayOfFileNames = $('#files > p').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get(); //['Jellyfish.jpg','Lighthouse.jpg' ..]
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEELs/)

Comment: @learner Glad to help.! If you feel anyone of the answers provided here satisfied your need, then try to click on the tick mark available with that answer in order to show your acceptance to the future visitors.. And it is not a compulsion... :)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
var AllFileNames = new Array();

$('#files > p').each(function(){
  AllFileNames.push($(this).text());
});
```